# Can't make request to "/" in MERN but other routes work normally

Tags: reactjs, json, express, proxy, mern

I have an express app running on port 4000 with two endpoints, `/` and `/admin`, they both return some simple JSON: {name: "Home"} or {name: "Admin"}.

`router.get('/', (req, res, next) => { res.json({name:"Home"}) })`

`router.get('/', (req, res, next) => { res.json({name:"Admin"}) })` in their respective routes/files.

I checked chrome network tools and both content-types are 'application/json'.

When I make a request to `/`, I get the error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, but `/admin` works normally.

I have this in package.json: `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",`

Here is my react home page:

```
import React from 'react';
import useFetch from '../hooks/useFetch';


const Home = () => {
    const {data, isPending, error} = useFetch("/");

    return (
        <div className="home">
            {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
            <h2>{data && data.name}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

And this is the fetch hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 400) {
                console.log("User not found");
            }
            if (!res.ok) {
                console.log("Couldn't connect");
            }
            console.log(res.headers.get("content-type"))
            return res.json();
            
        })
        .then(data => {
            setIsPending(false);
            setData(data);
            setError(null);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            setError(err.message);
            setIsPending(false);
        })
    }, [url])

    return {data, isPending, error}
}

export default useFetch;
```

More information:

- `useFetch('/admin')` works as expected
- I have tried adding and removing `app.use(express.json())` in express
- I have `console.log(req.path, req.method);` in middlware in express, `useFetch('/')` doesn't show up in the console, while `useFetch('/admin')` does. (Both are logged when accessing the localhost directly from browser)
- I have multiple endpoints in express, they all work normally with CRUD and mongodb atlas from react, only the root path doesn't work
- This line: `console.log(res.headers.get("content-type"))` outputs text/html for `/` and application/json for `/admin`

I'm not sure where the error is from exactly, maybe react sends a request to a wrong address and get some sort of `<html>` back? Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried opening the browser on the endpoint that you want to access?

Comment: Yes, on localhost:4000 I get {"name": "Home"}, in network tab the response-header content-type is application/json

Comment: When your app tries to fetch `/` it first sees your HTML file which is at the `/` so it doesn't ask a backend server for `/`. Try not using `/` or add `/api` to the end of the proxy and use `/api`

Comment: Thanks! is this a known issue in MERN? What can I google to know more exactly?

Comment: I wouldn't call it an issue.  Even in official docs, there is an example setup suggesting that `/` is the app and not the backend. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/